# How to get index of something or something else from url

Tags: javascript, url

I'm trying to make something happen if the url contains a certain word, but the word needs to change from page to page, heres the code I've got…

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('mens-' || 'footwear-') > -1 ){
 // do something here
} else {}
```

this works for 'mens-' but not for 'footwear-'

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You need test the individually i.e. `if(window.location.href.indexOf('mens-') > -1 ||  window.location.href.indexOf('footwear-') > -1)`

Comment: how embarrassing … thanks @Satpal

Comment: Logic operators will evaluate to the last value checked in the expression. || will always be true as soon as one thing is true, so saying `a || b` is a common way to say 'use a if it's true, if not b'. Your `'mens-' || 'footwear-'` evaluates to `'mens-'`. You can check this quickly by copy + pasting it into your browser console to see what it evaluates to.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Satpal, but you can try use regex, like this:

```
if (/(mens-|footwear-)/.test(window.location.href)) {
// do something here
} else {}
```

It is super simple example... and here I just try to get a gist...